# how customized the decimal points of data label in bar graph in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have bar chart below which looks like below - in that i have measure for Achievement % (in this graph 100% showing with two decimal i.e. 100.00%)
[image]

but i got a feedback from leadership that "100% value should not be in decimal". I played a lot with dax and formatting but did not get the result like below. (like shown in below graph, i want only 100% without any decimal i.e. 100% and rest all value should be with two decimal)

[image]

is this possible in PowerBI like excel. if yes then what will be the workaround.

Please suggest

Regards,
SK

Comment: Zero effort to present a reproducible question. Unclear and not useful.

Comment: I modified my question, hope this is much clear now.